# NuGet: What is the folder convention for Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: nuget

What is the folder convention for Windows Phone 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its "sl4-WindowsPhone71" for now as thats the automatic 1, not too sure if they will change it to something better for the next NuGet release.